# How many ways we can pass the variable through the navigation between the pages?

Tags: php

Which is Better And Secure way to Pass the variable through the navigation between the pages?

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"? Is it secret information? Or do you want to ensure the site user cannot modify the value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three ways can pass the variable through the navigation between the pages:

1. Put the variable into session in the first page, and get it back from session in the next page.
2. Put the variable into cookie in the first page, and get it back from the cookie in the next page.
3. Put the variable into a hidden form field, and get it back from the form in the next page.

Comment: Which is Better And Secure way to Pass the variable through the navigation between the pages?

Comment: May be Session is more safe bcz most of the time used in server side code.